# When did we start expecting a store to have bags for our purchases?

Tags: consumer-goods

In the United States, I expect that I could walk into any store and they would have bags for me to put my purchase in.

When did stores start providing this service?

I would accept any non-US history as an answer.  I'm mostly interested in how we moved from a world with no mass-produced bags into one where bags are everywhere ( and when that happened, of course ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://nymag.com/thecut/2013/12/bag-envy.html

> In the age of street vendors and sprawling town markets, shoppers
>   carried purchases in their own baskets and bowls. It wasn’t until the
>   early 1800s, writes Pamela Klaffke in Spree: A Cultural History of
>   Shopping, that stores began to provide packaging themselves. The mass
>   production of paper had cheapened the cost of wrapping, and stores
>   would use string to create makeshift handles.

So roughly at the middle of the industrial revolution.